# Tracking current location when application is closed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation

Can you track someone's location continuously while my app is not open?

Comment: I can physically follow people without opening whatever app you have written. Is that enough?

Comment: @H2CO3, +1, Yeah! That is completely enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can if device iOS above 4.0.

For more information [user this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yashesh, according to the link when u switch to other app the app continue to run in background. What i asked is that my app is not in memory and user have allowed to use location services, is it possible that we access user current location even then?

Comment: Yes.you can access user current location